# Problem in a rubic cube

Tags: experimental-mathematics

What guarantee that we can permute a rubic cube in such a manner that no two small square of same colour in one side are placed together(vertically and horizontally). I can make it in a systematic way, but is there any theoritical logic, so that we can ensure that. Please help me.

Comment: I would normally ask this sort of question on mathematics SE.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the *Mathematica* computer language and should be moved or closed.